# Save html content as docx format which is not opening in ms word

Tags: html, python-2.7, docx

I want to create a docx file with my python code using a html content. Im directly writing into file with .docx extension.
   This is opening in Libre office but unfortunately in MS Word it is not opening. It showing as corrupted format. Why this is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was wrong. MS word wont support **.docx** format. Instead use **.doc** format which will support in both application!!!